# Complicador não dá erro, porém o programa não inicia

Tags: c, struct, console

estou aprendendo estrutura de dados com a linguagem C, porém, percebi que deveria estudar um pouco mais de struct e ponteiros, em um dos exercícios que me foram passado é de criar struct com dia, mes e ano, e depois fazer uma função que recebess uma quantidade de dias e retornasse em que dia, mes e ano ele estária exemplo 01/01/2021, 15 dias, ele deveria retorna 15/01/2021.

Depois de corrigir alguns erros que apareceu na hora de compilar no terminal consegui fazer o executavel dele, porém o console abre e fica escura, não aparece nada para digitar, abaixo está meu código e o erro.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

typedef struct dma{
    int dia;
    int mes;
    int ano;
};

typedef struct dma data;

int mesGrande[7] = {1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 11};

int verificadorAnoBissexto(int ano){
    if(ano % 4 != 0){
        if(ano % 400 == 0){
            return TRUE;
        }else{
            return FALSE;
        }
    }else{
        if(ano % 100 == 0){
            return FALSE;
        }else{
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
}

int verificadorDeMesGrande(int ano){
    int verificador;
    for(verificador = 0 ;verificador < 7 ;verificador++){
        if(ano == mesGrande[verificador]) return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}

void acrecentadorDeDias(data acres){
    if(verificadorAnoBissexto(acres.ano)){
        if(acres.dia == 29 && acres.mes == 2){
            acres.dia = 1;
            acres.mes = 3;
        }
    }
    if(verificadorDeMesGrande(acres.ano) == TRUE && acres.dia == 31){
        if(acres.ano == 12){
            acres.dia = 1;
            acres.mes = 1;
            acres.ano++;
        }
        acres.dia = 1;
        acres.mes++;
    }
    if(verificadorDeMesGrande(acres.ano) != TRUE && acres.dia == 30){
        acres.dia = 1;
        acres.mes++;
    }
}

data fimEvento(data inicio, int duracao){
    int contador;
    for(contador = 0 ;contador <= duracao ;contador++){
        acrecentadorDeDias(inicio);
    }
    return inicio;
}

int main(){
   data a, b;
   scanf ("%d %d %d", &a.dia, &a.mes, &a.ano);
   int dura;
   scanf ("%d", &dura);
   b = fimEvento (a, dura);
   printf ("%d %d %d\n", b.dia, b.mes, b.ano);
   system("pause");
   return 0;
}
```

[image: Console não apresenta os printf]

Se possível poderiam explicar também o que aconteceu para que eu não cometa o mesmo erro no futuro, estarei bastante agradecido.

Desculpa se errei alguma coisa no tópico é meu primeiro.

**Resolvido** O problema foi que não coloquei um printf antes do scanf por isso o "Erro" aconteceu, ele já estava esperando os dados.
**Correções** Para os próximos usuários que forem pegar esse código como referencia, existe um erro nele `ano == mesGrande[verificador]` troque no código esse ano por mes e também onde ele é iniciado.

Comment: Olá... Parece que você não instruiu o programa a escrever nada antes de ler os dados. Observe que você tem um 'scanf', e só então o 'printf'. Para obter o resultado desejado, coloque uma instrução de escrita antes do primeiro 'scanf', algo do tipo: 'printf("Informe uma data");'.

Comment: Aqui: `if(ano == mesGrande[verificador])` não creio que tenha muito sentido comparar com ano. Tudo indica que o programa está aguardando que você informa a data e depois a duração.

Comment: Obrigado Marcos, o erro era realmente esse, erro da cabeça mesmo, eu esqueci de colocar um printf antes, e ele já iria direto para Scanf.

Anonimo, obrigado também, acabei de arrumar no código.

Comment: Na realidade isto não é um "erro", simplesmente o programa estava aguardando a entrada. A exibição de uma mensagem ajuda a sinalizar que está aguardando mas em um grande número de casos este tipo de mensagem é totalmente desnecessário. Quem for utilizar o programa deve estar ciente das entradas requeridas.